# Does GitPython works with Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitpython

If "yes", is there any difference when it's used with Python 2. ?

I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-python/EDxALGpv7ds), but I would say the answer isn't clear for me.

Thanks.

Comment: The post you link to says that the maintainer is not interested currently in making `GitPython` Python 3 compatible.

Comment: "But to my mind, git-python 0.3 and earlier are rather stable, which is why a port to python 3 would make sense there."
Was a bit confusing for me :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the link says is that it does NOT work with Python 3.X.

The replying fellow then goes on to comment that if someone wanted to port it to Python 3 (make it work with Python 3) they would do well to use a more stable version of GitPython than the newest release.

You will need to use Python 2. in order to use that module.